# Trouble with removing elements from the array as well as dynamically on screen in p5js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, p5.js

I am creating a brick breaker game using p5js. What I am trying to accomplish is to have the bricks dissapear from the array, as well as on the screen when the ball hits them. However, when I console log the brick that was hit by the ball , I get undefined. I believe it is because the function which is used to show my bricks is in the "draw" function of p5, which makes it generate new bricks over and over again, thus resulting in undefined each time.

Here is the github link to the whole project https://github.com/NikolaP93/Brick-Breaker

I have tried creating the bricks in the setup function, but the show function does not work inside of the setup function for some reason.

```
 for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
    bricks[i] = [];

    for(j=6;j>0;j--) { 
        bricks[i][j] = new Brick(i*50, j*30, 20, 40);
        bricks[i][j].show();

        if(ball.hits(bricks[i][j])) {
            ball.yspeed = 3;
            bricks[i].splice(j,1);
            console.log(bricks[i][j])
        }

    }

}
```

I believe that the actual loop is good to go, however, I believe that I don't know how to properly display/hide the bricks and this is causing the issue. When I log my own array, it shows that an element has actually been spliced, but it doesn't disappear from the screen, leading me to believe that it is a newly created array.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I console log the brick that was hit by the ball , I
>   get undefined.

This is to be expected, add a console.log prior to the removal of the brick and you'll get:

```
Brick {x: 550, y: 150, h: 20, w: 40}
```

The `undefined` is essentially further confirmation that the brick has been spliced from the array!

You can go one step further than this and log the array itself when you hit a block using `console.log("bricks")`:

```
(12) [Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(5)]
```

You can see that the block has been removed as one of the arrays only has 5 elements.

```js
let brick;
let bricks = [];


function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400);
    brick = new Brick(300, 350, 10, 50);
    ball = new Ball();


    //create bricks 12x6
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        bricks[i] = [];

        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            bricks[i][j] = new Brick(i * 50, j * 30, 20, 40);
        }
    }

}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(255);

    brick.show();
    brick.move();
    ball.move();
    ball.show();

    //check for collision and change direction between the main brick and the ball
    if (ball.hits(brick)) {
        ball.yspeed = -3
    }

    // display the bricks
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < bricks[i].length; j++) {
            bricks[i][j].show();

            
            // remove bricks
            if (ball.hits(bricks[i][j])) {
                ball.yspeed = 3;
                bricks[i].splice(j, 1);
                console.log(bricks)
            } 
        }
    }
 
}

class Brick {
    constructor(x = 300, y = 350, h = 30, w = 50) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.h = h;
        this.w = w;
    }

    show() {
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }

    // main brick movement
    move() {
        if (this.x > 0) {
            if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
                this.x -= 10;
            }
        }
        if (this.x < width - 50) {
            if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
                this.x += 10;
            }
        }
    }

  

}

class Ball {
    constructor(x = 300, y = 250, r = 10, xspeed = 3, yspeed = 3) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.xspeed = xspeed;
        this.yspeed = yspeed;
    }

    show() {
        fill(0)
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r);
    }

    // check the position of the ball if it's withing boundaries
    move() {

        // if it leaves the width, change direction
        if (this.x > width) {
            this.xspeed = -this.xspeed;
        }
        else if (this.x < 0) {
            this.xspeed = Math.abs(this.xspeed);
        }

        //if it leaves the height, change direction

        if (this.y > height + 50) {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.y < 0) {
            this.yspeed = Math.abs(this.yspeed)
        }

        

        this.x += this.xspeed;
        this.y += this.yspeed;
    }

   

    hits(brick) {

        // check if the circle is intersecting with the brick, still need to test if the ball is inside the brick

        if(this.x + this.r >  brick.x &&
            this.x - this.r < (brick.x + brick.w) &&
            this.y + this.r >  brick.y &&
            this.y - this.r < (brick.y + brick.h)) 
         {  
           return true; 
         }

    }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```